# php web socket script bat file remain open

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a script that initiate a web socket via cmd prompt and the cmd prompt needs to remain open. How do I do this?

Using the example from PHP website for the command line section.
I have a `.bat` file with the code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\path_to_script\pear_web_socket_server.proc.php
```

But everytime I run this bat file. The cmd window is closed instantly after the script has ran once.

Answer (score 0):

Add a pause to the script. For example:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f C:\path_to_script\pear_web_socket_server.proc.php
Pause
```

Save the file with the .bat extension.

Comment: doesn't work. the only thing that happened was a cmd prompt window with `"Press any key to continue..."`. And if a key was pressed, the window is closed. Task is ended in task manager.